# How can I get semantic HTML elements like <header> to inherit <div> CSS styling?

Tags: html, css

I have some global CSS applying styles to `div` like setting the background color based on my color theme, but this doesn't apply to semantic elements like `nav`, `header` and `main`. How can I get semantic elements to inherit styles from `div` automatically?

Comment: What styles? Are the tags you're talking about children of a div and just not inheriting? For many CSS properties you can use [`<property>: inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit)

Comment: "What styles" - I set the `background-color`, `transition-timing-function`, `color`, `font-family`, `border-color` all based on the active color theme. It would be fine if I could just set these styles on `body` but many of them aren't `inherit` by default so I just applied the styles to every `div`. I can just apply all these styles to the whole list of semantic elements but was hoping for a snippet to make semantic elements inherit all styles from `div` which I could include in my `reset.css` instead of cluttering my stylesheet with semantic element names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add them to styles:

```
div, nav, header, main {
  background-color: white;
  // other styles
}
```

Look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more info